# Websocket application with grails

Tags: grails, groovy, websocket, groovy++, gretty

I wanted to implement websocket functionality in my application.Using groovy & grails on server side.So, please can you help me how to write a websocket server in groovy...Please help me as this is a critical requirement in my application.
I heard something related to Gretty server for websocket.Can anyone guide me on this.
Please help me asap.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://jolorenz.wordpress.com/2015/07/21/websockets-with-grails/

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Atmosphere plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere)

Not sure if it works with Grails 2.0 yet